# Accordion control is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use the [accordion](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/157f614a827c0de3f3413895ff508b7e8a2d2d6a/src/accordion) for implementing it in one of my use case. Accordion is not working properly. when I click on heading it is not opening and closing.

My HTML code:

```
  <accordion close-others="true">
<accordion-group  heading="Fruits">
<div class="section">
    <ul><li>Apples</li><li>Mango</li><li>Ban</li></ul>
  </div>
</accordion-group>
<accordion-group  heading="Animals">
<div class="section">
    <ul><li>Dog</li><li>Rat</li><li>Cat</li></ul>
  </div>
</accordion-group>
<accordion-group  heading="Test">
<div class="section">
    <ul><li>Test1</li><li>Test2</li><li>Test3</li></ul>
  </div>
</accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

I have included accordion.js file in my scripts.

Am I missing any other files to be added in my project?

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap JS file? Any errors in the console?

Comment: i guess you are missing the module dependency, angular-ui on your app

Comment: bootstrap JS File is included

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are suffer from above code.you don't have complete source library.

take a look here for little idea...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<h4 ><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseage"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> Age</a></h4>
<p class="clearfix"/>
<div id="collapseage" class="collapse out">
<ul class="list-inline">
This is very simple way of accordian....
<li><span>1. 0-15</li>
<li><span>2. 15-25</span></li>
<li><span>3. 25-35</span></li>
<li><span>4. 35-50</span></li>
</ul>
</div>

<h4 ><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#fruit"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> Fruit</a></h4>
<p class="clearfix"/>
<div id="fruit" class="collapse out">
    <ul class="list-inline"><li><span>Apples</span></li><li>Mango</li><li>Ban</li></ul>
  </div>
  
<h4><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#animals"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> Animals</a></h4>
<p class="clearfix"/>

<div id="animals" class="collapse out">
    <ul class="list-inline"><li>Dog</li><li>Rat</li><li>Cat</li></ul>
  </div>

  <h4 ><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#test"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> Test</a></h4>
<p class="clearfix"/>
<div id="test" class="collapse out">
    <ul class="list-inline"><li>Test1</li><li>Test2</li><li>Test3</li></ul>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are confuse with that, you can use bootstrap way like...

```
<div class="age-lists df-demography-cat">
<div class="demography-htag df-inhtag">
<h4 class=" arvo-bold ft-14 pull-left"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseage"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> Age</a></h4>
<input  class="switch-handle" type="checkbox" checked>
</div>
<p class="clearfix"></p>
<div id="collapseage"  class="collapse out">
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li><span>0-15</span></li>
<li><span class="selected fa">15-25</span></li>
<li><span>25-35</span></li>
<li><span>35-50</span></li>
</ul>
<span class="add-more-dfbtn"><button type="button" class="btn-default small">add more</button></span>
</div>
</div>
```

That is very Simple just work on collapse in/out with internal page content referencing.
 as mention on image

[OpinionBureau Feasibility Collapse in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqg3b.png)

[IRB Feasibility Collapse out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH1Tv.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Due to some reasons, I have to use the accordion which I mentioned above.

Comment: you missed out css , bootstrap & angular js. or their compatibility.